# AttributeError: 'ir.ui.view' object has no attribute '_render'

Tags: odoo, render, attributeerror, dms

I succeeded to install Odoo 15 module DMS (Documents) ex. OCA in Odoo 16, but get error when running the module:

File "/Users/Karunia/odoo16/odoo/addons/dms/controllers/main.py", line 33, in document_onboarding_file
"html": request.env.ref("dms.document_onboarding_file_panel")._render(
AttributeError: 'ir.ui.view' object has no attribute '_render'

The above server error caused the following client error:
OwlError: The following error occurred in onWillStart: "Odoo Server Error"

I am new in Odoo developing and unable to solve the above error.

Comment: The `_render` method was removed, check [the commit message](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/880954ebfc1106411b7f7a7d60aee05dfae60893). Updating and getting the onboarding state function was renamed to [_get_and_update_onboarding_state](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/6c73ed6f4b8372aba698e34e930c664829d19595)

Comment: Thank you. It gives solution. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is you cannot install Odoo 15 module on Odoo 16 because the code for your module needs to be updated to v16.
for the issue above you need to call it like this:

```
request.env['ir.qweb']._render('dms.document_onboarding_file_panel', {
        "state": company.get_and_update_documents_onboarding_state(),
        "company": company,
})
```

Hope it solves your problem.